# Activity retain instance of Fragment on onSaveInstance

Tags: android, android-fragments, savestate

I'm writing an application where using **onSaveInstance(..)** to retain values on device config change(say device font, local).

Here application Activity using multiple Fragment to display. After chnage in config change when **coming back** to app then onCreate(..) execute and app checked if **Bundle** object is null. Now till this state app **didn't set** any Fragment child back but but still last set Fragment (before change in config) child started to execute it's life cycle method.

How can prevent it, one way to check Same Bundle object from Fragment child, same as Activity and return. But is there other way to remove child from Activity on device-config change!

Activity reference code to handle re-calling:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.reading_activity);

        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            init(savedInstanceState);
        } else {
            // Don't do anything
        }
    }
```

Here init(..) responsible to set Fragment child.

Comment: It is not so clear what you are asking for. Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: If I understand you correctly: after a config change, you want to show the right fragment(s) to reflect the config change? Instead, you get the previously show fragment(s)?

Comment: Can you show us some code? Like, how do you display the fragment? do you use a viewpager?

Comment: @Christine Bit different, Even I did not set any fragment on recall of onCreate, it is showing old fragment and it start to execute life cycle method. My understanding is, Activity should clear all old variable including what it's displaying, isn't !

Comment: Can you show us your Activity code?

Comment: Creating a demo code  from project will take time. Added reference code, please check. I will share more once it done, till then let me know if any suggestion.